# Errors for "sudo apt update" Lubuntu 20.04.01 LTS

Tags: updates

Can someone help me please how to repair all those errors? Thank you.

```
    ~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                  
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                            
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                    
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                  
Ign:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy InRelease                                         
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu focal Release                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Ign:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates InRelease                             
Err:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy Release                
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates Release        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Hit:12 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Later edit 1/2:

@stdcerr

```
~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                            
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                           
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]                         
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu focal Release                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]                         
Hit:8 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease                  
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

---

```
:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
        # Automatically generated by Calamares on 2020-12-24.
        # Lines starting with "deb" are mandatory, while lines starting with "deb-src"
        # are for more detailed package information.
        
        ## See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
        ## newer versions of Lubuntu.
        deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
        # deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
        
        ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of Lubuntu.
        ## Have you noticed a regression? Please report it!
        ## https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates#Regressions
        deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
        # deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
        
        ## Software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu team.
        ## Also, please note that software in Universe WILL NOT receive any review or
        ## updates from the Ubuntu security team directly. Updates in this repository
        ## are provided by volunteers, but most come from Debian.
        deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
        # deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
        deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
        # deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
        
        ## Software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu team,
        ## and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as your rights
        ## to use the software. Also, please note that software in Multiverse WILL NOT
        ## receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security team directly.
        deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
        # deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
        deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
        # deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
        
        ## Software from this repository contains tested security updates from the
        ## Ubuntu security team.
        deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
        # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
        deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
        # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
        deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
        # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
        
        ## Software from this repository may not have been tested as extensively as
        ## software contained in the main release, although it includes newer versions
        ## of some applications which may provide useful features. Also, please note
        ## that software in Backports WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the
        ## Ubuntu security team.
        deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
        # deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
        
        deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main
        # deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main
```

Later edit 2/2

@laurent

> sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa

```
:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                            
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                           
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]                         
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]                         
Hit:6 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease                  
Fetched 324 kB in 2s (172 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Comment: Why do you have `saucy` (13.10) repos on your `focal` (20.04) system?

Comment: Sorry, @OrganicMarble by mistake. Reagards.

Comment: Can you remove those `saucy` repos and re-run `apt-get update`?

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party repositories, so all security checks are on you to perform (can they be trusted? are they maintained? etc)  Given a PPA I looked up had it's last update early 2017 and doesn't provide support for releases later than 17.04, I'm betting you didn't perform your security checks, and should remove the PPAs.  https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team  https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa etc  (*did you look?  16.10/17.04 being the last supported release(s) should raise alarm bells security wise in your checks*)

Comment: Thank you @guiverc Can you tell me please more exactly which ppa should I delete? `sudo ppa-purge` ?

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa

Comment: Thank you @laurent Everything should be all right now, I hope. I edited the main question with the new-last `sudo apt update`

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.